# pattern matching in R using grepl

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I have a dataframe `dat` like this

`P            pedigree                            cas
1 M           rs2745406                              T
2 M           rs6939431                              A
3 M   SNP_DPB1_33156641                              G
4 M SNP_DPB1_33156664_G                              P
5 M SNP_DPB1_33156664_A                              A
6 M SNP_DPB1_33156664_T                              A`

I want to exclude all rows where the `pedigree` column starts with `SNP_` and ends with either G, C, T, or A (`_[GCTA]`). In this case, this would be rows 4,5,6.

How can I achieve this in R? I have tried

`multisnp <- which(grepl("^SNP_*_[GCTA]$", dat$pedigree)=="TRUE")`

`new_dat <- dat[-multisnp,]`

My `multisnp` vector is empty, but I can't figure out how to fix it so that it matches the pattern I want. I think it is my wildcard `*` usage that is wrong.

Comment: This should do the job: `dat2 <- dat[!grepl("^SNP_\\.*_[GCAT]$", dat$pedigree), perl = T]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following with `.*?` (match everything in non greedy way):

```
multisnp <- which(grepl("^SNP_.*?_[GCTA]$", dat$pedigree))
                              ^^^
```

Comment: This works! Could you explain what the `.*?` means? I know `*` means match the preceding stuff zero or more times but I'm not sure what this combination means.

Comment: `.` means any character.. `*` means as you know.. match 0 or more times.. and `*?` means 0 or more times in a non greedy way.. `*` is greedy by default and matches everything after it sometimes ignoring to match the pattern after `.*`.. hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I feel that there's an extra close paren invovled here, which is also present in the OP's code.

Comment: I think it was the close paren after the regex that needs to go.

Comment: It's not fixed. [edit] there you go. Although using `which` with `== TRUE` isn't useful.

Comment: @blakeoft thanks again.. i dont have an editor to test at the moment.. couldnt test syntax..

Comment: I can confirm that it works now, at least for the sample provided.

Comment: Try the code without the `TRUE` at the end, it is redundant. `which(grepl("^SNP_.*?_[GCTA]$", dat$pedigree))`

Comment: @plafort again.. couldnt check it.. but logically you are right.. updated.. :)

Comment: @blakeoft I removed the erroneous close parenth in my edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can subset `dat` like this

```
new_dat <- dat[!grepl("^SNP_.*_[GCTA]$", dat$pedigree), ]
```

Regarding the code that you've tried, I'm not sure that `grepl("^SNP_*_[GCTA]$")` will complete without an error since you aren't passing in an `x` vector to `grepl`. See `?grepl` for more info.